# using lapply to expand lists

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to expand out some input data that comes in character format. In the below example --

```
jv17 <- list(4.2017,5.2017,6.2017,7.2017,8.2017,9.2017,10.2017)
jv18 <- list(4.2018,5.2018,6.2018,7.2018,8.2018,9.2018,10.2018)
mylist1 <- list("jv17")
mylist2 <- list("jv17", "jv18")
```

This does what I want:

```
eval(parse(text = mylist1))
```

This does not:

```
eval(parse(text = mylist2))
```

The output I am looking for:

```
list(jv17,jv18)
```

I feel very confident this could be done with lapply but I'm not as good as I should be with it. Here is my best guess but I get an error that is not intuitive (at least to me).

```
lapply(x = mylist2, FUN = eval(parse(text = .)))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try  `list(mget(unlist(mylist1)), mget(unlist(mylist2)))`

Comment: Looks like `lapply(mylist2, get)` would work too.  You may want to read `help(lapply)` as you are trying to use a nested function in `FUN`, which is only doable with an anonymous function.